# In a SELECT command, how do I use data from one table to specify data in another?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have 2 tables. What is important is the `PlayerId` and the `Username`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Run] 
(
    [RunId]        INT       NOT NULL,
    [PlayerId]     INT       NOT NULL,
    [Duration]     TIME(7)   NOT NULL,
    [DateUploaded] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [VersionId]    INT       NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RunId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Run_Player] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PlayerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Player] ([PlayerId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Run_Version] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([VersionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Version] ([VersionId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Player] 
(
    [PlayerId]       INT       NOT NULL,
    [Username]       NCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [ProfilePicture] IMAGE     NULL,
    [Country]        NCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [LeagueId]       INT       NULL,
    [DateJoined]     DATE      NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PlayerId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Player_League] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([LeagueId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[League] ([LeagueId])
);
```

I have a select command:

```
SELECT 
    PlayerId, Duration, VersionId, DateUploaded 
FROM 
    [Run]
```

(with apologies in advance for my messy made up pseudocode), what I need it to do is:

```
SELECT (Player.PlayerId.Username)
```

What I basically need it to do, is instead of giving me just `PlayerId`, I need it to get the corresponding `Username` (from the other table) that matches each `PlayerId` (`PlayerId` is a foreign key)

So say for example instead of returning

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

it should return

```
John12, Abby2003, amy_932, asha7494, luke_ww
```

assuming, for example, Abby2003's PlayerId was 2.

I've done trial and error and either nobody's tried this before or I'm searching the wrong keywords. This is using VS 2022, ASP.NET Web Forms, and Visual Basic, but that shouldn't affect anything I don't think. Any syntax ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server**: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Also: `NCHAR(n)` is always fixed length and will be padded to the defined length with spaces - which is very often **NOT** what you want - I'd strongly recommend using `NVARCHAR(n)` instead. And also: `DateUploaded` sounds like a **DATE** - so why is it stored as a string?? ***Always*** use the most appropriate datatype - if you want to store a date - use `DATE` - not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for join the 2 Table togother

```
SELECT R.RunId
  ,R.PlayerId
  ,R.Duration
  ,R.DateUploaded
  ,R.VersionId
  ,P.Username
  ,P.ProfilePicture
  ,P.Country
  ,P.LeagueId
  ,P.DateJoined
   FROM Run R
   inner join Player P on R.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
```

Comment: lifesaver, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Usually in this case joins are used. You can join the two tables together, give them aliases (or don't, personal preference really), then select what you need. In this case, you would probably want an inner join. Your query would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT p.Username FROM [Run] r
INNER JOIN [Player] p ON r.PlayerId = p.PlayerId
```

Then if you need to you can put a `WHERE` clause after that.

More about joins [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)